# Change CPT Edit Target Link for Admin List

Tags: custom-post-types, filters, hooks, wp-admin, links

Hoping you can help with this conundrum of mine.

I have created a CPT, and am changing the link in the admin list pages for it to be the front-end permalink.  What I'd like to do now is to change the target to `_blank`, so it pops open in a new tab.

However, the `edit_post_link` filter does not appear to be working.

Here is what I currently have:

```
// swap the link for a #
add_filter( 'get_edit_post_link', function( $_url, $_id, $context ) use( $_pt ) { 
    
    // if it's the alerts post type
    if( get_post_type( $_id ) == $_pt ) {

        // get the frontend permalink to this item
        $_link = get_the_permalink( $_id );

        // return the front-end link
        return $_link; 

    }

    // default to the url
    return $_url;

}, 10, 3 );

add_filter( 'edit_post_link', function( $link ) {

    var_dump("HERE-----------------------------------------------------------------");

    $link = str_replace( '<a ', '<a target="_blank" ', $link );

    return $link;

}, PHP_INT_MAX );
```

I have also tried the filter like this as well:

```
add_filter( 'edit_post_link', function( $link, $post_id, $text ) {

    var_dump("HERE-----------------------------------------------------------------");

    $link = str_replace( '<a ', '<a target="_blank" ', $link );

    return $link;

}, 10, 3 );
```

Neither of these do anything, not even the `var_dump` shows in Admin List page for the CPT.  Please do note that I am removing the `post_row_actions` (well, all except trash) because I am pulling the data for the CPT's from an API, and I want zero editing capabilities, and that seemed the most logical route.

Is there another filter that I should be hooking into for this? Or is this something that is truly "broken" in WordPress?

Comment: What's really got me... I even went and did the "BIG" NO-NO and edits wp-includes/link-template.php's `edit_post_link` function just to see if it's just me and adding the target there, only to have that not work either... so... I'm thinking this may be a Wordpress issue?!

Comment: That's because for Admin List pages, `edit_post_link()` function of `wp-includes/link-template.php` file is never used. As the name of the file suggests, it's a template function, to be used is your theme's template files. It's not used in Admin list page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Issue-1:

[`edit_post_link()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/edit_post_link/) is a template function, to be used in theme template files. It's not used in the Admin pages. So you'll not get the `edit_post_link` filter hook for the Admin list pages.

### Issue-2:

[`get_edit_post_link()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_edit_post_link/) function however, is used in Admin list pages. So you'll get the `get_edit_post_link` filter hook for the Admin list pages.

### Issue-3:

Even though you'll get the `get_edit_post_link` filter hook for the Admin list pages, it is used mainly for the link itself, not the entire `<a>` tag. So you can't change `<a href="Edit-link">` to `<a href="Edit-link" target="_blank">`. WordPress core doesn't allow that.

Check the core CODE here, it doesn't allow `target="_blank"`:

```php
printf(
    '<a class="row-title" href="%s" aria-label="%s">%s%s</a>',
    get_edit_post_link( $post->ID ),
    /* translators: %s: Post title. */
    esc_attr( sprintf( __( '&#8220;%s&#8221; (Edit)' ), $title ) ),
    $pad,
    $title
);
```

### Possible solution:

You can still alter this behaviour by hooking into [`wp_list_table_class_name`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_list_table_class_name/) filter hook and extend the `WP_Posts_List_Table` class with something like `WP_Custom_Posts_List_Table` to override the [`column_title()`](https://github.com/WordPress/wordpress-develop/blob/6.1/src/wp-admin/includes/class-wp-posts-list-table.php#L1056-L1142) function to achieve `target="_blank"` for your specific custom post type.

It's probably a lot of work only for opening a link in a new tab, but I don't see any other **proper** alternative implementation. Easier JavaScript implementation is possible, but that's more of a hacky solution.

Comment: Yeah, that's alot more work than I'm willing to put in on this site as well.  It's an astronomy site that I'm doing in my spare time.   I don't want to go the JS route either.  It will likely only ever be me in this area of he backend, so I can just try to remember to right-click and open in new tab ;)